# ggplot- misiing values in scale x

Tags: r

I made that plot-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz4Cu.png)

and that the code:

```
**plot <- ggplot(df, aes(mounth, value, fill=year))
plot <- plot + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')+ facet_grid(. ~ variable)+ geom_text(aes(label = value),size=1.8,vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_grid(. ~ variable) + ggtitle("חסות הנוער: כמות השמות לפי דיווח \n שנת 2019 VS שנת 2020")
plot**
```

but the first month(3) and the last month(9)  disappeared from the X axis and I can not get them to appear.
Also does anyone know if there is a possibility that the plots will appear in 2 lines and not in one?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your data. The issue is that you are providing a numeric variable to the x-axis. Instead you can use `factor()` so that each number can appear in the axis. Here the code (And please next time include your data of a sample of it):

```
#Code
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(mounth), value, fill=year))
plot <- plot + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge')+
  facet_grid(. ~ variable)+
  geom_text(aes(label = value),size=1.8,vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_grid(. ~ variable) +
  ggtitle("חסות הנוער: כמות השמות לפי דיווח \n שנת 2019 VS שנת 2020")
```